# Create Date Range Slider in Django Form

Tags: python, django, slider, date-range

I am facing some implementation issue in Django. My app reads data from excel uploaded by the user. It extracts dates from it such as earliest date and recent date. I am able to show these two date extracts in html form and let users custom select the time range. (thru' django forms.py). To make a better user experience, I want to create a date range slider in the form that will allow the users. So far, I am able to find a Django package called django_range_slider. (https://github.com/shaklev/django_range_slider/tree/master/test_slider) I can also implement this packages features correctly as long as I have an integer values for the range. The moment I put date values on, it does not work very well.

Here is **forms.py**:

```
from django import forms
from .fields import RangeSliderField
from .models import TestModel
from django.forms.widgets import SelectDateWidget
class TestFieldForm(forms.Form):

class Meta:
    model = TestModel
    fields = ['range_field','name_range_field','label_range_field']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TestFieldForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['name_range_field'] = RangeSliderField(minimum=30,maximum=300,name="TestName")
    self.fields['range_field'] = RangeSliderField(minimum=10,step=10,maximum=102)
    self.fields['label_range_field'] = RangeSliderField(label=True,minimum=1,maximum=100)

class fcPForm(forms.Form):

label_range_field = RangeSliderField(label="Date Range",minimum="",maximum="") # with label (no name)
```

Here is **models.py**:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
class TestModel(models.Model):
    #range_field = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #name_range_field = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    label_field = models.DateField()
```

Here is **views.py**:

```
from .models import actuals,forecast,TestModel

def analyze(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = InputForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    dataType = request.POST.get("DataType")
    request.session['dataType']=dataType
    if form.is_valid():
        sheet = request.FILES['FileLocation'].get_sheet()
        book = request.FILES['FileLocation'].get_book()
        #do calculation to find out eDate,lDate
        fcForm = fcPForm(initial = {'label_range_field':(eDate,lDate)})

        if fcForm.is_valid():
            cdFC = fcForm.cleaned_data

        return render(request,'abc.html',{'earliestDt':earliestDate,'latestDt':latestDate,'form':fcForm,context)
```

Here is fields.py:

```
from django import forms
from .widgets import RangeSlider

class RangeSliderField(forms.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = kwargs.pop('name', '')
        self.minimum = kwargs.pop('minimum',0)
        self.maximum = kwargs.pop('maximum',100)
        self.step = kwargs.pop('step',1)
        kwargs['widget'] = RangeSlider(self.minimum, self.maximum, self.step, self.name) 
        if 'label' not in kwargs.keys():
            kwargs['label'] = False
        super(RangeSliderField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here is abc.html:

```
   <form action="{% url 'DjangoApp:xyz'%}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
                            <table>
                                {{ form }}
                            </table>
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit Data">
                        </form>
```

If I pass regular integer values to the form, range slide shows up and I am able to interact with it. When date values are passed as it shows up in the text box, but the slider disappears. Open to other suggestions/different way of doing things.

Comment: If you want to use a slider for a date range you'll need to define a date for your start point and your end point, then calculate the percentage between those two points your target is and apply that to your slider. Sliders require a start and end and, technically, time has neither.